# Wrong intuition of Lagrange multiplier method

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I have already read multiple questions on this topic but none of them provided me a satisfying answer to the following point:

Let be $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, where $f{ x \choose y}=x^2+y^2$ and $g :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, with $g{ x \choose y}=2x-y-5$. We now impose the contraint $g{ x \choose y}=0$. This gives us a set of points ${x \choose y}$ which can be described by a curve. If we follow the curve and plug in the values into $f$ we are simply looking for the highest or lowest value. So far so good.

[image: intersection of images]

The image above shows the case where both images of $f$ and $g$ intersect. But what if the images of $f$ and $g$ didn't intersect? (where the image of a function is defined by: $im(f):=\{ z \in \mathbb{R}~|~ \exists {x \choose y} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f{x \choose y}=z\}$). Then I would say that there is no solution to the optimization problem. However, in some questions here on MSE they said that this would make no sense but I don't understand why it would make no sense? What is wrong with this picture in my mind?

May be someone can shed light on this issue.

Comment: Intersection is defined for sets, not  functions, so the question is meaningless as it is.

Comment: @Gribouillis, so if I simply replace the term _function_ by _image of the function_ it would be legit?

Comment: The image of a mapping has a strict definition. I'm not sure we're thinking about the same thing. Try to make the question really unambiguous.

Comment: Usually in Lagrange multiplier problems we are trying to find a local extrema for a function f(x,y) subject to the constraint that it lies on g(x,y), where the problem can be abnormal or normal. So of course, the extremal point (x,y) must lie on f(x,y) and satisfy the constraint g(x,y).

Comment: @Gribouillis I edited my question, maybe it is clearer now.

Comment: It is much clearer now. I couldn't make a better answer than @KevinCarlson's below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image shows the set $\{(x,y,z):g(x,y)=0\}$ and the set $\{(x,y,z):z=f(x,y)\}$. So this has nothing to do with the image of $g$. However it is correct that we are trying to minimize $z$ over the intersection of those two sets, and there would be no solution if the sets did not intersect. This can only occur if the set of $(x,y)$ with $g(x,y)=0$ fails to intersect the domain of $f$.

Comment: In linear optimization, a point where the constraint is satisfied is called a 'feasable point'.  So there needs to be a feasable point in the domain of $f$.